# why is jvm returning false when comparing two objects of same type?

Tags: java, object, heap-memory, equals-operator

```
public class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
       {
        String s = new String("test");// *** 
        String s1 = s.toUpperCase();

        String s2 = s.toLowerCase();

        String s3 = s1.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println(s==s1);//first case

        System.out.println(s==s2);//second case

        System.out.println(s==s3);//third case
       }
    }
```

1) Why does it return false for the third case(commented). Both s3 and s  are pointing **test** yeah? But it seems JVM creates another object named **test** for s3 in the heap memory. But it is not the same for the second case(commented). It uses the object which was previously created as s(commented as *** in the code). Why is that?

2) And what happens to s1 object **TEST** because s3 is created from s1. Will s1 be destroyed or will it be in heap?

Comment: For part 2 of your question, s1 hangs around until it's no longer references. In your example above it's still referenced. If you set s1 to null it would be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you Jason. can I have the answer for question 1 please

Comment: Look at the link in the first comment.

Comment: Not the answer for my question. I'm asking about object created in heap memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `String s = new String("test");` object will be created in heap area (not inside String pooled area) but any other string returned after any operation will be created in String pooled area. To answer your question:

1. `s==s3` returned false as they are two different objects.
2. `s1` won't be collected by garbage collector until it is being referenced.

Comment: Thank you Sukhpal Singh. Cleared the doubt.